# Change reference frame titles in Beamer

Tags: beamer

The file `prop.tex` contains the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=american]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{prop_ref.bib}

\usepackage{newcent}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{The Title}
Qsddhksh  ksjdhfkhs kdjfhkjshf kshjdkfjhs kjdhf~\parencite{aaa01,ccc02}.
Tskdjfskj k hksdhfkjhk~\parencite{ggg08} jsdk hkshjdkfjh skhj kjsdhf
jkhskdhfkhsjkd kjshdkfjh~\parencite{bbb03,ddd04,eee12}.
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the file `prop_ref.bib` contains the following:

```
@Article{aaa01,
author = "B C Aaaa and F E Dddd",
title = "This is really the title, yes, this is the title, the title, the title, the title, the title, the title, the title, the title, the title",
year = "2001",
volume = "10",
pages = "100-120",
journal = "Some Journal"
}

@Article{ccc02,
author = "G H Cccdddfff",
title = "This is another long title and you call this a long title? Maybe it is not really long",
year = "2002",
volume = "130",
pages = "150-162",
journal = "Some Other Journal"
}

@Article{bbb03,
author = "A S Bbbbbbbb and W Q Rrrrr and G H Cccccc",
title = "This is another long title but it is really longer than usual, but maybe, just maybe, it might have been shorter, really shorter",
year = "2003",
volume = "55",
pages = "250-272",
journal = "The Old Journal"
}

@Article{ddd04,
author = "R D Dddddddddggg",
title = "This is another short title that should have been shorter if I had not made it longer",
year = "2004",
volume = "12",
pages = "160-172",
journal = "Nobody's Journal"
}

@Article{eee12,
author = "R F Eeeeerrr",
title = "I wonder what the title of this article issss sssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssss ssssss ss sssss sssss ssssssssssssssss ssss ssss sssssssss sss ssssssss",
year = "2012",
volume = "12",
pages = "160-172",
journal = "The Journal Journal"
}

@Article{ggg08,
author = "M M GggDddddxxxddddggg",
title = "Ohhhh Wooooo Ooooooooooooooo Wooooooooooo Haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
year = "2008",
volume = "124",
pages = "190-212",
journal = "What A Journal"
}
```

When I generate the pdf file, the reference frames have the headers **References I** and **References II**.

Is it possible to change these to **References** and **References (continued)**?

Comment: Have you tried using an overlay i.e. put the frametitle References on the first slide and use References (continued) on later slides?

Comment: @cfr, how do I do that?

Comment: All the references are placed in one frame in the `.tex` file but become multiple frames when generated in the `.pdf` file due to the `[allowframebreaks]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to II 8.1, the beamer template `frametitle continuation` stores the text inserted at the end of the title of a breakable frame. In your case the predefined option `from second` is applicable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
\frame[allowframebreaks]{{References}\lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][(continued)]
\frame[allowframebreaks]{{Bibliography}\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

As you could see, if no second argument provided, beamer typesets **(cont.)** by default.